# matlab create float values, but it doesnt plot it

Tags: matlab

With this code, I am trying to plot single precision float values to a graph.  First, I read in a document and convert the first column to double.  I divide the first column by 1000000 (to get a time a seconds) and then convert it to single precision float.  Finally, I plot it.

```
Time_1=str2double(Time{:,1});%convert string from the first column to double'
Time_single=single(Time_1/1000000); % convert double to float'
plot(Time_single,'r')
```

The second line of this code gives me float values, for example 2,4567 and 7,5678 but if I want plot these values, Matlab draws just 2 and 7 and not 2,4567 and 7,5678

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Can you provide the content of `Time{:,1}` ?

Comment: if you do `plot(Time_1)` (so _before_ the division and casting to single), do you get the correct values ?

Comment: Time is a text document, I use the first column of it. The values are correct.